# Get facebook email and save to membership DB using Oauth Login

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook, oauth, webforms

I recently implemented facebook Oauth on my site. I am using webforms and membership database so when someone logs in for the first time using facebook they are asked to choose a username. Now this worked fine until I changed `"requiresUniqueEmail=false"` to `"true"`. **(Check EDIT for update on this)**

For some reason this change in my *Web.configs membership provider* messes up the whole facebook login.

When I have made this change and try to set a username for the new user (and thereby creating it) it says "Invalid Email". It makes no sense to me, The only thing I changed is that I require a unique Email. And now I cant register using facebook.

I need this setting since I allow registration *without* social media, and when they register this way I don't want them to re-use an Email. What can I do?

**EDIT:** I checked my membership database and it turns out that in the "membership" table the users who registered with facebook has an email value of NULL. That is, their email does not get saved in to the table. This must be why it cannot be unique. How can I fix this?

I assume I have to add it somewhere here (I'm using the RegisterExternalLogin.aspx that gets generated in webforms):

```
protected string ProviderName
        {
            get { return (string)ViewState["ProviderName"] ?? String.Empty; }
            private set { ViewState["ProviderName"] = value; }
        }

    protected string ProviderDisplayName
    {
        get { return (string)ViewState["ProviderDisplayName"] ?? String.Empty; }
        private set { ViewState["ProviderDisplayName"] = value; }
    }

    protected string ProviderUserId
    {
        get { return (string)ViewState["ProviderUserId"] ?? String.Empty; }
        private set { ViewState["ProviderUserId"] = value; }
    }

    protected string ProviderUserName
    {
        get { return (string)ViewState["ProviderUserName"] ?? String.Empty; }
        private set { ViewState["ProviderUserName"] = value; }
    }
```

However the table "UserOpenOauthData" in the database (standard generated oauth database) does not even have a column for Email, only the "Membership" table does, so I have no idea how to add the email. I really need this and I have been searching for days without finding any examples of how to do it, only MVC examples available or examples where the database has a table named "OauthMembership" that has a column for email, which mine does not.

If anyone can please help me get the email from facebook and save it to my database I'd be so happy. Really dont want to turn off the non-external login.

**Want to try?** Simply go to Visual studio (I use VS12), create a Webforms project using asp.net 4.5 and let it create the template for you. In the Account-folder you find all the methods they use for handling members. Set your facebook AppID etc in startup and then let it create the database by registering ur first user using facebook. As you can see, it does not save email. And If you try to set email to "Unique" in membership provider you cannot create a user using facebook.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you could do is create your own method that checks for email, then call it before the user gets created. If you are using CreateUserWizard there is a method called `OnCreatingUser` you can use.

Code behind CreateUserWizard:

```
protected void RegisterUser_CreatingUser(object sender, LoginCancelEventArgs e)
{
    TextBox EmailTextBox = RegisterUser.CreateUserStep.ContentTemplateContainer.FindControl("Email") as TextBox;
    String emailParam = EmailTextBox.Text;

    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strCon))
    {
        con.Open();
        using (SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand())
        {
           cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Email FROM Memberships WHERE Email=@emailParam";
           cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@emailParam", emailParam);

           using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
           {
              if (reader.Read())
              {
                  LabelExists.Text = "This e-mail is already registered";
                  e.Cancel = true; //Cancels registration
              }
            else
            {
                //create the user
            }

         }
      }
     con.Close();
   }
}
```